# Error: Variable used within its own initial value?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

i'm trying to convert source code developed in Xcode 6.4 into Xcode 7. I'm getting some new errors. Below code which works fine in Xcode 6.4 is not working in Xcode 7

```
 for (index: String, category: JSON) in json["payload"]["categoryList"] {
        let category:Category = Category(category : category)
      categoryList.append(category)
    }
```

Comment: you should either rename your `category: JSON` or `category:Category`, because their naming conflicts.

Comment: but it worked fine in swift 1.2

Answer (score 0):

Update your code like below,

```
for (index: String, cat: JSON) in json["payload"]["categoryList"] {
        let category:Category = Category(category : cat)
      categoryList.append(category)
    }
```

Comment: I'm getting error saying that "use of unresolved identifier cat"

Answer (score 0):

It's good habit not to confuse the compiler by reusing variable names as parameter names and local variables in the same scope.

Better write:

```
for (index: String, category: JSON) in json["payload"]["categoryList"]  {
  let categoryListItem = Category(category : category)
  categoryList.append(categoryListItem)
}
```

or even

```
for (index: String, category: JSON) in json["payload"]["categoryList"] {
  categoryList.append(Category(category : category))
}
```

The type annotation `Category` is not needed. The compiler infers the type

Comment: Thanks but I'm getting error saying that "use of unresolved identifier category"

Comment: You might have to specify the type of the array : `json["payload"]["categoryList"] as! [JSON] `

Answer (score 0):

```
for (index: String, categoryJSON: JSON) in json["payload"]["categoryList"] {
    let category:Category = Category(category : categoryJSON)
    categoryList.append(category)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually i found answer for my question in  swift 2.0 they changed syntax of for loop

```
for (key,categoryJSON):(String, JSON) in json {
        //Do something you want
        let category:Category = Category(category : categoryJSON)
        categoryList.append(category)
```

}